# QFileDialog::getOpenFileName is very slow on mac

Tags: cocoa, qt, qfiledialog

I am working on sample qt project which involves reading the existing directories , requirement is that i have to use getOpenFileName function and while working on it i have observed that this function works well on windows but on mac by using the native the window its responsiveness is very slow can anyone know how to speed up this?? currently i am using following function

QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, Caption, defaultPath, filters);

Comment: What version of Qt I you using?

Comment: No, you can't do anything about it. By the way - it doesn't depend on your operation system, but on computer. I have the same - on my laptop it works fine, but on computer i have to wait like 3 seconds after close dialog.

Comment: @cmannett85: I am using qt 4.7.4(64 bit)version

Comment: It's a Qt problem and it won't likely get fixed because nobody wants to admit it's a Qt problem. Fill a folder with 3,000 items and call getOpenFileName on it. The problem is still present in 2013 Qt 4.8 & Qt5.